# Is there a way to plot a layout in Julia, using different colours per plot?

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I am trying to plot a layout in Julia env using the code below

```
x = 1:100
y = sin.(rand((Normal()), 100,4))
# plot
plot(x,y)
# layout
plot(x,y, layout = (4,1), color = [:red,:blue])
```

What I expected was a coloring of each plot with either red or blue. The result was 4 plots that had both red and blue. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to the dimension of `color`:

```
julia> [:red,:blue]
2-element Vector{Symbol}:
 :red
 :blue
```

It is reasonable to think it will apply this scheme to each 2 items of the original array. However...

```
julia> [:red :blue]
1×2 Matrix{Symbol}:
 :red  :blue
```

this will be applied each 2 columns. So it should be as follows:

```
julia> plot(x, y, layout=(4, 1), color=[:red :blue])
```